# How can know which file contain the variable definition?

Tags: environment-variables

In my os:

```
echo $CLUTTER_IM_MODULE
fcitx5
```

How can know which file contain the variable definition?
I knew that we can define env in .bashrc or /etc/bash.bash.
It cost much time to get files which contain string `CLUTTER_IM_MODULE`.

```
sudo grep  -r  CLUTTER_IM_MODULE  /
```

Is there a smart way to achieve my target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure that the variable is defined in a shell profile script **and** you have a version of `locate` that supports both extended regular expressions and NUL-separated output (e.g. `mlocate` or `plocate`), you could run something like this (which will be much faster than running `grep -r`):

```
locate -0 --regex '/(\.(bash_)?profile|(bash)?\.?bashrc|etc/profile.d/|etc/environment$)' |
  xargs -0r grep -H '[^$]CLUTTER_IM_MODULE='
```

Notes:

1. grep's `-H` option ensures that the filename will always be output with a match, even if only one filename is returned by `locate` (which is unlikely, but it doesn't hurt to use -H anyway).
2. you might want to use grep's `-i` option for case-insensitive matches too.
3. if there are other locations where shell profile scripts might be found, or other names that they might have, then you'll need to adjust the regex to suit. e.g. my original regex didn't search for `/etc/environment` (which is another place that shell variables can be defined on some systems), so i added it.
4. This won't and can't tell you which file the variable **WAS** actually defined in, it can only show you the files that **MIGHT** be responsible for the current value of the variable (it has no way of knowing which one was actually executed, it can only see that the variable is being set in a script).
5. `locate`'s database is usually only updated once per day.  If the profile script was created after the last run, the file won't be found.
6. depending on permissions of the files, you may need to run this as:

   ```
   sudo locate ... | xargs -0r sudo grep -H
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Bash doesn't keep track of that. Try grepping through the different files for CLUTTER_IM_MODULE.